# Spring Boot 2.4.2 and Thymeleaf 3.0.12 - access static methods

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

Since I switched to **`Spring Boot 2.4.2`** my `Thymeleaf` templates are broken. When I want to access a static member in Spring Controller I get the following error:

> Exception processing template "template_name": Instantiation of new
> objects and access to static classes is forbidden in this context.

The code looks like:
`th:text="${T(com.test).testMethod("1234")}"`

Do you have any recommendation to fix this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This change is the part of [Thymeleaf 3.0.12](https://www.thymeleaf.org/releasenotes.html#thymeleaf-3.0.12). They [improve restricted expression evaluation mode security](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/issues/809) by restriction of the access to static code (@identifier@ in OGNL, T(identifier) in SpringEL). What they have done by themselves? ... "*Avoided instantiation of new objects and calls to static classes*" as stated in release notes. You may move the JAVA calls into your controller and put the result into the view model. After just access this variable from Thymeleaf template.

Comment: Thanks for your input! I moved the static method in the domain model which was also know in the view model.

Comment: Also replaced all static methods with non-static ones.

Answer (score 10):

Another quick fix is the use of th:with

```html
th:text="${testText}"
th:with="testText=${T(com.test).testMethod("1234")}"
```

Source/Kudos: https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/issues/816#issuecomment-791921248 and https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/issues/816#issuecomment-826401631

Answer (score 5):

There is a workaround to use method from beans registered at the Spring Application Context with the @beanName syntax. Like this:

```
<div th:text="${@testService.testMethod('123')}">...</div>
```

http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/springmvcaccessdata.html